# Interface With additional property derived from base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class

I try to extract some operation into an interface with some additional property like this :

Base Entity Class:

```
public enum MyClassEnum
{
    classA,
    classB,
    classC
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public string entityA { get;set; }
    public int entityB { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have some class that Derive from MyBaseClass:

```
public class ClassA : MyBaseClass{}

public class ClassB : MyBaseClass
{
    public string AnotherEntity { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC : MyBaseClass
{
    public string AnotherEntity2 { get; set; }
    public string AnotherEntity3 { get; set; }
}
```

I try to  have an interface like this (this is I got so far):

```
public interface IMyClassRepository
{
    void Create(MyBaseClass param);
    void Update(MyBaseClass param);
}
```

And the concrete class it should be like this:

```
public class ClassBRepository : IMyClassRepository
{
    private readonly BaseRepository _baseRepository;

    public ClassBRepository
    {
        _baseRepository = new BaseRepository();
    }

    public void Create(MyBaseClass param)
    {
        // will use automapper to do the mapping
        var theClassB = MyBaseClass.TranslateTo<ClassB>();

        // How i can design the interface that accept additional Property on class B?

        // last save the operation to DB..
        _baseRepository.Save(theClassB);
    }
}
```

> **UPDATE**

I will create `IMyClassRepository` use `Factory` like this:

```
public class MyClassFactory
{
    public IMyClassRepository CreateInstance(MyClassEnum param)
    {
        switch(param)
        {
            case MyClassEnum.ClassA
            {
                return new ClassARepository;
            }

            case MyClassEnum.ClassB
            {
                return new ClassBRepository;
            }

            case MyClassEnum.ClassC
            {
                return new ClassCRepository;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in the end have operation class like this:

```
public class ConcreteOperationClass
{
    private IMyClassRepository _myClass;
    public ConcreteOperationClass(MyClassEnum param)
    {
        _myClass = new MyClassFactory().CreateInstance(param);
    }

    public void CreateMyClass(MyBaseClass param, // this should be a parameter class B or Class C needed)
    {
        _myClass.Create(param, // additional property for classB or classC);
    }
}
```

The Problem is how I create the implementation of `IMyClassRepository` with additional property from `ClassB` or `ClassC` ?

Comment: Maybe inheritance isnt the solution here if they are all that different.

Comment: `void Create(MyBaseClass param);`? Can you explain what this method supposed to do? (Normally `Create` would return something it just created, but it is not the case in your design).

Comment: @JustinPihony but they have same entities, and same operation.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it should save some records.

Comment: If the method requires a property of ClassB then it will need to take a ClassB as parameter.

Comment: @76484 yes, that's the problem, but since they have same property derive from the base class and have same operation. so, I try to extract that to an interface that i can use on concrete class but how I can do that with additional property from ClassB and ClassC?.

Comment: You can do it by *casting* param to ClassB or ClassC - but this would be horrible. If the method requires the param to be a ClassB, why not give it a ClassB?

Comment: Your answer to AlexeiLevenkov makes no sense.  Why would a method named `Create` be saving some records?  It seems to me that `Create` and `Update` both don't need any parameters because the object that they are creating or updating is the object that they're a member of, so you'd simply use `this` to refer to the object in those methods.

Comment: Why do you need to know the exact class of a parameter? If you want to save or update your entities - those should be either implemented properly as a methods of specific classes or be done generically (for example, with proper ORM mappings). Can you show an example implementation of this interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, you're trying to design something similar to a repository pattern? If that's the case, you could  create a repository implementation for all your entities. For this, you will need to create a generic interface that works with concrete implementations of your entities...

```
public interface IMyClassRepository<T> where T : MyBaseClass
{
    T Get(int id);
    void Create(T param);
    void Update(T param);
}
```

Then create an implementation of this repository for each entity...

```
public ClassARepo : IMyClassRepository<ClassA>{...}
```

And then you could create a factory object that serves these concrete implementations on the fly. Something like...

```
var repository = RepositoryFactory.Resolve<ClassB>(); 
ClassB entity = repository.Get(234);
entity.entityA = "new value";
repository.Update(entity);
```

You don't even have to implement it yourself if you use a D/I Container such as Windsor Castle where you can define implementations and services through config file, and even swap them without having to recompile the whole app.

Comment: @reptildarat it's exactly the same answer to the same question. Having to create an instance of a factory object everytime you need a repository instance is ugly. At least you should make your `CreateInstance` method a static method...or make the factory object a singleton object...or even better use a dependency injection container such as Windsor Castle to avoid those forever-growing `switch` cases

Comment: @reptildarat needless to say that having an `enum` to determine what kind of entities to return is far too useless. That's what generics are for, to infer the underlying data type at runtime. Have you thought of what'd happen when you need another entity in your project? That means another `enum` value and another `swicth...case`...that's massive design issue because you've got way better options since the .Net Framework 2.0...GENERICS

Comment: But then, i will need to create "Create" on ConcreteOperationClass for each entities right? not just 1 method that accepting all parameter(classA, classB, classC) which is my goal.

Comment: @reptildarat I'm not too sure what means, but the beauty of Windsor Castle is that you don't need to create ANYTHING AT ALL. It resolves dependencies based on config files

Comment: Well, DI/ IoC a side (because i cannot use it "easily" on ASMX project), I see your point tho. I can extract this to generic repository pattern.

Comment: @reptildarat "i cannot use it "easily" on ASMX project" why not? I've used it extensively on WCF projects without any issues or roadblocks...it's a server-side implementation after all

Comment: well, it's ASMX (web service, the reason behind this is because the client is still use .net 1.1) project, not WCF. and second, i cannot instantiate the DI / IoC on application_start (global.asax). so to resolve the dependencies, i still need to create the DI object for every operation class.

Comment: @reptildarat I still don't see the problem. The service runs on the server, not the client and if hosted on a web server and the factory object is a singleton it'll get create only once. I don't understand??? Anyway, I'm glad you're on the right track already